# Get all company geocodes in specific area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to get all the geocodes of a specific company through Google search APIv3?

ex. I do a search for 'booster juice, Ontario' and it'll return all of the geocodes for booster juice locations in Ontario. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [textSearch of the places-library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) , but the results are limited to 20 items.

**Before you start:** it's not allowed to create a business-listing(when it's the primary purpose of the implementation)  feeded with data  of the Maps-API.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then if I require all the ontario locations? A limit of 20 doens't suffice.

Comment: Given it allows for 50km radius. I could, in theory look for booster juices in each major city and store them.

Comment: In theory, but this also is not allowed: "you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information" https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3